# rustc/cargo not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, rust

After installing rust on my windows 7 computer, I decided to run a simple hello world program in vscode in a file named main.rc, but on putting the following code in terminal

```
rustc main.rc
```

in order to run main.rc, my terminal started giving the following messages:

```
'rustc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I also put the following code in terminal

```
cargo init
```

and this time also my terminal gave the following message

```
'cargo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[image: terminal error messages]

Then I thought to put all installed rust folders in my C drive where my python folders were also present

[image: C Drive]

But no change occurred.
Then I thought to put rustc file path to environment variables, but still, all these efforts went in vain.

[image: environment variables screenshot]

Comment: How have you installed Rust? [The basic installation](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install) should work.

Comment: Did you restart your shell after adding `cargo` to the path? Also note that the file is called `main.rs` and you can run your rust program using `cargo run` from a directory where a `Cargo.toml` is present. You can create a new rust project using `cargo new <project_name>`.

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for helping me, but  I downloaded rust from the same link, and my cmd in the end showed 'rust downloaded successfully' {or a similar statement}, but running rust through vscode terminal gives errors which I have pointed

Comment: @frankenapps Thank You sir for showing interest to help this beginner . Yes, I restarted vscode after adding cargo to path. But I am not able to find any file named cargo.toml in .cargo and .rustup folders. I even tried to redownload rust , and cmd also proved that rust was downloaded, but still running rust program in vscode gave above mentioned errors.

Comment: @frankenapps And as mentioned sir, on putting commands like `cargo run` or `cargo new <project_name>`, same message ie `cargo is not recognised as internal or external command` appears in my vscode terminal. And as Cargo.toml is not present, cant understand why, I am confused of what to do now

Comment: Did you download and run the windows installer, to install Rust?

Comment: I would also like to inform that my vscode downloaded files are in D Drive while rust downloaded files are in C Drive

Comment: @frankenapps I just downloaded rust through the option `DOWNLOAD RUSTUP-INIT.EXE(64 bit)` and tried to run rust program through vscode. I think I did not use windows installer as  on downloading rust a separate cmd like window popped up and nowhere I saw windows installer like thing

Comment: is this windows xp?

Answer (score 7):

I went through that in the past using Windows. I didn't have Microsoft C++ Build Tools installed. As you are using Windows

1. Make sure you have Microsoft C++ Build Tools installed ([Download it here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/))
2. Download and install RUSTUP-INIT.EXE ([Download the 32-BIT here](https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/i686-pc-windows-msvc/rustup-init.exe), [Download the 64-BIT here](https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/rustup-init.exe)). One can also download from [here](https://rustup.rs/).

For other Rust installation methods, read [this page](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html).

One can also use Windows Subsystem for Linux. If that's the case, run the following and follow the instructions.

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

For additional information on how to install, [check this link](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install).

Once the installation is complete, you may want to consider using an IDE. [Here](https://areweideyet.com/) you'll see comparison of various editor features. At the present time, [VS Code](https://areweideyet.com/#vscode) and [IntelliJ](https://areweideyet.com/#intellij).

If you end up using IntelliJ, you'll want [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8182-rust).

---

In case you end up having problems with Rust in the future, apart from posting your question on SO with the tag `rust` you may want to consider the following discussion platforms:

- [Official Discord](https://discord.gg/rust-lang)
- [Official Users Chat](https://users.rust-lang.org/)
- [Mozilla Matrix Chat](https://chat.mozilla.org/#/room/#rust:mozilla.org)
- [Rust Subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/)

Answer (score 6):

For me, instructions such as `rustc main.rs` worked in PowerShell and the Command Prompt, but they did not work in Visual Studio Code's Terminal.

Restarting my computer fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the following command in my bash terminal to get it to work.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the file called rustup-init.exe from your search bar on Windows. It will add the requires file to classpath. And then just restart the machine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33921920)